# Use `window.top.$` to send ajax request in iframe, but the referer is not the url of iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, referer

There are two html files, an `index.html` and `inner.html`.

** index.html **

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<iframe src="./inner.html" frameborder="1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It has referenced jquery.

** inner.html **

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Get Data by AJAX">
<script src="./inner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

** inner.js **

```
const $ = window.top.$

$('#button', window.document).click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data.json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        context: this
    })
})
```

On the server side, I will print the header `referer`.

The url to open index.html is: `http://localhost:3000`.

I found when I make ajax requests in inner.html, using the `$` from `window.top`, the `referer` printed in server is `http://localhost:3000`, which is the url of the outer page.

I expected to be the url of iframe, to be `http://localhost:3000/inner.html`, but can't find a way if I insist using the jquery from `window.top`.

PS: If I move the code `<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` from `index.html` to `inner.html`, and use `window.$` to send ajax requests in inner.html, the referer is what I expect: http://localhost:3000/inner.html

This is a simplified demo for my project, in which we have to use the jquery provided by the platform, which is `window.top.$`

Comment: My assumption would be jQuery is pulling the XHR from the parent's window, thus sending the request from the parent. You can alter this behavior using the `xhr` setting in ajaxSettings, or by altering the `xhr` setting of the ajax request itself.

Comment: @KevinB I have the same guess, is there any way to make jQuery sending from current window?

Comment: Here's where that functionality is defined in the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/ajax/xhr.js Because the function is defined from the parent window, `window` will be the parent window's window.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the link! Seems like I have to provide a custom xhr from current window. Which works!